# MySQL Select Query - Get only first 10 characters of a value

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Ok, so here is the issue.

I have a table with some columns and 'subject' is one of the columns.
I need to get the first 10 letters from the 'subject' field no matter the 'subject' field contains a string with 100 letters.

For example,

Table - **`tbl`**.
Columns - `id`, `subject`, `value`.

SQL Query:

```
SELECT subject FROM tbl WHERE id ='$id';
```

The result I am getting is, for example

> Hello, this is my subject and how are you

I only require the first 10 characters

> Hello, thi

I can understand that I can remove the rest of the characters using php substr() but that's not possible in my case. I need to get the excess characters removed by MySQL. How can this be done?

Answer (score 353, accepted):

Using the below line

```
SELECT LEFT(subject , 10) FROM tbl
```

[MySQL Doc.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left)

Answer (score 65):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(subject, 1, 10) FROM tbl
```

Comment: I feel like this is the more complete answer, since `LEFT` may not address specifics (yes, like those raised by the OP) dealing with extractions that need to start mid-string.

Answer (score 12):

Have a look at either [Left](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left) or [Substring](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html) if you need to chop it up even more.

Google and the MySQL docs are a good place to start - you'll usually not get such a warm response if you've not even tried to help yourself before asking a question.

Comment: A sample would have been a bit more helpful.

Comment: @RoccoTheTaco I totally disagree - also your down vote is very harsh. read `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask` the very first point is `Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question?`.  This question is so easily answered by a simple and quick Google search. I didn't just want to give the OP the answer I wanted to show them HOW to find the answer - *much* more useful in my opinion.

Comment: I understand what @Steve is saying (makes sense) but I came here from Google. Yes, the original question was lazy but the fact that I don't have to go somewhere else helped me. It's also nice that SO is building up a library of answers to simple questions like these. Also equals more advertising $ for SO.