# Retrieving the First n letters from table in sql

Tags: php, sql

I saw this post which had my ans: [MySQL Select Query - Get only first 10 characters of a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14959166/mysql-select-query-get-only-first-10-characters-of-a-value)
How to do the same using php ?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by substr function. Following is the working example with code.

http://sugunan.net/demo/substr.php

```
<?php 
$full_str = "Hello, this is my subject and how are you";
$firstn = substr ( $full_str , 0 ,10 );
echo $firstn;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `substr()` function.  Read about it here http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

```
$shortString = substr($longString,$startPoint,$numberOfCharactersToReturn);

eg: substr('abcdefg',0,3);

// returns 'abc'
```