# I have table containing names and I want to show the output sorted alphabetically but I want to show only 2 record of each alphabet

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
Table
```

**Id**       **name**

1              Akhil

2              Akira

3               Anuj

4               Bia

5               Bina

6              Chetu

7               Chini

8              Chikna

9              Chana

---

Output

**Id**       **name**

1              Akhil

2              Akira

3               Bia

4               Bina

6              Chetu

7              Chini

Comment: How have you attempted this so far, and where are you failing? If you show your query we can probably help, but StackOverflow questions aren't about simply requesting code to solve your problems.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Select Query - Get only first 10 characters of a value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14959166/mysql-select-query-get-only-first-10-characters-of-a-value)

Answer (score 0):

Here the Query. In the Result are more field, but you can remove them. They are only to see how the Query works

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    @nr :=  IF(@old_val = SUBSTRING(t.name,1,1),(@nr +1),1) AS nr,
    @old_val:=SUBSTRING(t.name,1,1) AS tmp,
    t.name FROM mytable t,
    (SELECT @nr:=0, @old_val:='') AS TMP
  ORDER BY NAME
) AS result WHERE nr < 3;
```

Please let me know if it works for you