# How do I correctly compare a MySQL text field to a string of arbitrary length?

Tags: mysql, indexing

Say I have a table that uses a string as its Primary Key. For example, a sessions table ( I will keep this to 4 characters so I can make my examples clearer).

I will also add an Auto Increment column to keep my example closer to reality (in case it makes a difference).

```sql
CREATE TABLE sessions (
  `id` INT AUTO INCREMENT,
  `key` CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(`key`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idx_key` ( `key` )
);
```

I can insert data into the table.

```
INSERT INTO sessions (`key`) VALUES ('abcd');
```

Because this is a session ID it comes from a browser, so I don't trust it and use proper bind values in the code that handles the requests. A malicious user can send various strings here but they will always end up as strings and not injection attacks. That's fine. MySQL will happily truncate this data and issue a warning.

```
INSERT INTO sessions(`key`) VALUES ('abcdefg');
Warning (Code 1265): Data truncated for column 'key' at row 1
```

However, this is only "fine" (it's not fine, but whatever) for creating rows. The same operation first *looks for* a row before trying to insert it. You know - upsert. MySQL does not bother to truncate *this* data, and decides it is not in the table.

```
SELECT * FROM sessions WHERE `key` = 'abcdefg';
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

This means that my insert from earlier was even more not fine, because when I *insert* the data, MySQL truncates it to a value that *does* exist.

```
INSERT INTO sessions (`key`) VALUES ('abcdefg');
Warning (Code 1265): Data truncated for column 'key' at row 1
Error (Code 1062): Duplicate entry 'abcd' for key 'idx_key'
```

The website code does not know the constraint on this column and I have no intention of giving it this information.

How can I get MySQL to compare only the first N characters of the string, where N is the (max) length of the text field?

Comment: I updated your key exampls to be letters rather than numbers, as per your actual question.

Comment: The `AUTO_INCREMENT` column has to be the primary key.

Comment: @Barmar - The only indexing requirement for `AUTO_INCREMENT` is that it be the first column in _some_ index.  It does not have to be the PK.

Answer (score 1):

There are [various MySQL functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html) for doing this in a round-about way.

The easiest to use is `LEFT` [Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_left), [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14959166/mysql-select-query-get-only-first-10-characters-of-a-value)

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as numb FROM sessions WHERE `key` = LEFT(:stringVar,4)
```

Where `:stringVar` is a PDO Prepared Statement placeholder (and so completely safe in MySQL) for the given session value.

Therefore

if `:stringVar = 'abcdefg'` then the SQL above will check `key = 'abcd'`  and ignore the rest of the string.

For flexibility, you can also use `RIGHT` if you so wish (in this case that would return 'defg').

## WARNING:

With MySQL 5.7 and above, inserting data longer than the field length (as referenced in your question), by default will now **abort the Insert / Update** and return an error. Be aware of this and look this up.

So; to avoid this, apply the `LEFT` fnctionality upon insert as well:

```
INSERT INTO sessions (`key`) VALUES ( LEFT('abcdefg',4));
```

---

(untested)

If your `key` column length(s) are variable; you can dig them out dynamically, using MySQL INFORMATION_SCHEMA:

```
SELECT `CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH` as ColumnLength FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS`
WHERE `COLUMNS`.`DATA_TYPE` = 'char' AND `COLUMNS`.`TABLE_SCHEMA` = '<db_name>' AND `COLUMNS`.`TABLE_NAME` = '<table_name>'
```

In full:

```
INSERT INTO sessions (`key`) VALUES ( 
    LEFT(:stringVar, 
        (SELECT `CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH`  
         FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS`
         WHERE `COLUMNS`.`DATA_TYPE` = 'char' AND `COLUMNS`.`TABLE_SCHEMA` = '<db_name>' AND `COLUMNS`.`TABLE_NAME` = '<table_name>') ));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `SUBSTRING` method.

Given N is the (max) length of the text field, you can say

```
SELECT * FROM sessions WHERE `key` = SUBSTRING('abcdefg', 1, N)
```

if N = 4 then we have

```
SELECT * FROM sessions WHERE `key` = SUBSTRING('abcdefg', 1, 4)
```

Comment: Only MySQL knows the 4, which means I can't put it in the query directly... Could I create a stored procedure with the 4 in it, and thus it is version controlled alongside the CREATE TABLE and I can use a single variable? Should I?

Comment: Yes @Altreus you should. that should work and also makes more sense for re-usability and consistency of anticipated length of characters for CREATE and SELECT queries.

Answer (score 0):

By chopping to 4 characters, you are saying that the *rest of the string is not used for testing for equality*.

> The website code does not know the constraint on this column and I have no intention of giving it this information.

Storing into `CHAR(4)` implies truncttion.  If you truncate the string, you have lost information.  So the test cannot be performed.

> How can I get MySQL to compare only the first N characters of the string, where N is the (max) length of the text field?

`LEFT(input_string, 4)` will do that.  That "4" can be buried in the API that lies between the user and the database.  You should not allow the user to directly perform `INSERTs`.

Other notes...

Beware of `CHAR` -- it pads to the specified length with spaces.  Then it ignores trailing spaces when comparing.  Hence `'abc '` and `'abc'` will compare equal, as will the truncation of `'abc def'`.

`INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY ..` is a single-statement way of either inserting or updating.

Maybe you would be interested in this:  You could "digest" the text with some "hashing" function, such as MD5 or SHA256.  The digest is a fixed length.  It can be used for testing for equality.  (There is an extremely low chance that two different texts would hash to the same value.)